# Digging Into Specific Index Of Javascript Array

Tags: javascript

new to Javascript and having a hard time understanding some data manipulation.

I'm pulling over some data from a var from PHP to JS and cannot figure out how this is indexed! Any help is greatly appreciated!!

```
$heretimePh1 = "{rate:958.741566}, {rate:958.741566}, {rate:958.741566}, {rate:958.741566}, {rate:7669.932528}, {rate:7669.932528}, {rate:7669.932528}, {rate:7669.932528}, {rate:5000}, {rate:7669.932528}, {rate:7669.932528}, {rate:7669.932528}, {rate:7669.932528}, {rate:7669.932528}, {rate:7669.932528}, {rate:7669.932528}, {rate:7669.932528}, {rate:7465.172304}, "
```

Here is my code for trying to create a var for the first value of 958.741566

```
var a = <?php echo $heretimePh1; ?>;
var b = a['rate'];
var c = b[0];
```

But that does not seem to be working out at all, any pointers in the right direction much appreciated, unsure what I'm missing as most documentation is what seems to be the usual []

Comment: `$heretimePh1` isn’t JSON. Encoding that string just results in another string; strings don’t have a `rate` property. You’re not even attempting to parse anything on the JavaScript side. Does the data come from somewhere specific? If so, try to make it valid JSON. If it’s a hard-coded string, rewrite it to valid JSON.

Comment: Yeah I might be over my head a little on that, I was having issues just using echo $heretimePh1 it seemed, I did update it as well back to echo, still don't have any luck

Comment: $heretimePh1 is just a large string? I think that's the part that has been kicking my ass

Comment: Sorry, ignore the part of my comment that said _“Encoding that string just results in another string”_ and _“attempting to parse”_; not sure what I’ve been thinking there. Of course, you still need `json_encode`, otherwise you’ll end up with an unquoted string in JS, which results in invalid syntax. However, `json_encode($heretimePh1)` needs to result in JSON with the expected structure. In this case, `$heretimePh1` ideally needs to be defined as `[ [ 'rate' => 958.741566 ], [ 'rate' => 958.741566 ],`…`]`. But _how_ to do that depends on where the data comes from.

Comment: Thanks for all that information, @SebastianSimon. The data is coming from a mysql query via PHP, 'rate' is my own wording for what in my mind is the key, and the value is the data pulled from the query, I am trying to not treat this like a dict as it does seem to be one but that is why I am trying to narrow down into the 'rate' in var B, with some python knowledge and not a lot of JS this is where I am struggling to make sense or how to split up this array (If that's what it is) and then iterate through it [0], [1] ,[2], etc.

Comment: Being a noob it takes way longer than you would think to use gettype, was able to do that and then explode to get what was needed, @SebastianSimon appreciate the help and the pointer "depends on where the data comes from".

Comment: _“depends on where the data comes from”_ only referred to the possible solution: if it’s a string that you wrote yourself, you’d have to change it manually to valid JSON; if it’s a string (or array) that comes from some API, e.g. a database call, then you’d have to change it _programmatically_ to valid JSON, or request valid JSON or an array to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close out this question, the data coming from the PHP var `$heretimePh1` was a string, even though it had multiple values and ,'s from a mysql query using PHP `gettype` showed it was NOT an array and was a string. Using the PHP function `explode("," , $heretimePh1);`  I was able to get was I was looking for.